# How to set up datatables for dynamic tables

Tags: cakephp, datatable

I have a dynamic table name and tried for datatables in Cake PHP controllers. But it didn't worked.

```
<?php
 $data = $this -> DataTable -> getResponse(Model,action);
?>
```

Here I do not have any specified model name as I am accessing table model via `ClassRegistry::init()` in controller . I do not have exact Model name here. What should I then use here? Also what action should I specify to get the data?

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
$this->controller->loadModel($Model);
$this->controller->{$Model}->{user any model action}
```

{user any model action} : you have to make action which has common name for all Model.